# Delphi 10.4.2 FMX How to put address in String into TCivicAddress?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

What is the way to initialize `TCivicAddress` and put address info into it? I even tried to set everything separately, it still encounter errors.

```
var cAddr: TCivicAddress;
cAddr.FeatureName := '10';
cAddr.Thoroughfare := 'Xxxxx Xxxxx Xxx';
cAddr.SubLocality := 'Xxxxxx Xxxxx Xxx';
cAddr.PostalCode := '12345';
cAddr.Locality := 'Xxxxxx';
cAddr.AdminArea := 'Xxxxxxx';
cAddr.CountryName := 'Xxxxxxx';
```

Is it not possible to create `TCivicAddress` from string? I can't seem to find documentation online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TCivicAddress](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Sensors.TCivicAddress) is a class that need to be instanciated before accessing any member.

```
cAddr := TCivicAddress.Create;
cAddr.FeatureName := '10';
```

Comment: is it possible to put whole address in string at once?

Comment: I don't think so. But if you have a lot of such conversion, you can derive your own class from TCivicAddress and add a FromString function which does the job.